# Using Json with JS

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, getjson

Hi folks working with a json table here at the minute the Json arrays are being passed using a  JS file. Got my PHP file working with a DB to generate the arrays from the db. How could I pass this array from the php page to the JS file?

Current JS code

```
function ctrlRead($scope, $filter) {
    // init
    $scope.sortingOrder = sortingOrder;
    $scope.reverse = false;
    $scope.filteredItems = [];
    $scope.groupedItems = [];
    $scope.itemsPerPage = 10;
    $scope.pagedItems = [];
    $scope.currentPage = 0;
    $scope.items = [
        {"id":"1","name":"name 1","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 1","field4":"field4 1","field5 ":"field5 1"}, 
        {"id":"2","name":"name 2","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 2","field4":"field4 2","field5 ":"field5 2"}, 
        {"id":"3","name":"name 3","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 3","field4":"field4 3","field5 ":"field5 3"}, 
        {"id":"4","name":"name 4","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 4","field4":"field4 4","field5 ":"field5 4"}, 
        {"id":"5","name":"name 5","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 5","field4":"field4 5","field5 ":"field5 5"}, 
        {"id":"6","name":"name 6","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 6","field4":"field4 6","field5 ":"field5 6"}, 
        {"id":"7","name":"name 7","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 7","field4":"field4 7","field5 ":"field5 7"}, 
        {"id":"8","name":"name 8","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 8","field4":"field4 8","field5 ":"field5 8"}, 
        {"id":"9","name":"name 9","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 9","field4":"field4 9","field5 ":"field5 9"}, 
        {"id":"10","name":"name 10","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 10","field4":"field4 10","field5 ":"field5 10"}, 
        {"id":"11","name":"name 11","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 11","field4":"field4 11","field5 ":"field5 11"}, 
        {"id":"12","name":"name 12","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 12","field4":"field4 12","field5 ":"field5 12"}, 
        {"id":"13","name":"name 13","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 13","field4":"field4 13","field5 ":"field5 13"}, 
        {"id":"14","name":"name 14","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 14","field4":"field4 14","field5 ":"field5 14"}, 
        {"id":"15","name":"name 15","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 15","field4":"field4 15","field5 ":"field5 15"}, 
        {"id":"16","name":"name 16","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 16","field4":"field4 16","field5 ":"field5 16"}, 
        {"id":"17","name":"name 17","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 17","field4":"field4 17","field5 ":"field5 17"}, 
        {"id":"18","name":"name 18","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 18","field4":"field4 18","field5 ":"field5 18"}, 
        {"id":"19","name":"name 19","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 19","field4":"field4 19","field5 ":"field5 19"}, 
        {"id":"20","name":"name 20","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 20","field4":"field4 20","field5 ":"field5 20"}
    ];
```

Comment: I don't get your actual problem. Have you looked at `json_encode()`?

Comment: Rather than using the arrays above i want to use the arrays i've generated with the json_encode and the DB

Comment: Still not sure, but maybe you're searching for something like this: `<script> $scope = <?php echo json_encode( $PHParray ); ?>; </script>`

Answer (score 1):

You need [json_encode](https://www.php.net/json_encode). If you're calling this function with AJAX, it's as easy as adding this at the end of what you have:

```
echo json_encode($scope.items);
```

I would think all the other properties that are apart of `$scope` could be handled in your JavaScript.